# How to debug "illegal start of expression" in Java?

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

In Jcreator, there are 12 errors here, I don't know how to fix it. It says "illegal start of expr....".

If I change something, suddenly, 50 errors more.

```
public class Practica_figura {
    Class Figura() {
        private float base;
        private float altura;
        private float radio;
    }

    public void asignar(float ba, float al, float ra) {
        base = ba;
        altura = al;
        radio = ra;
    }

    class Cuadrado extends Figura()
    {
        private float base;
        private float altura;

        public void calcular_area(float b, float a) {
            float res = base * altura;
        }

        public void calcular_perimetro(float a) {
            float resp = 4 * a;
        }

        public void rareac() {
            return area;
        }

        public void rperic() {
            return perimetro;
        }
    }

    class Triangulo extends Figura()
    {
        private float base;
        private float altura;
        private float la;
        private float lb;
        private float lc;

        public void asignar(float a, float b, float c) {
            la = a;
            lb = b;
            lc = c;
        }

        public void calcular_area(float b, float a) {
            float res = (base * altura) / 2;
        }

        public void calcular_perimetro(float a) {
            float resp = 4 * a;
        }

        public void rareat() {
            return area;
        }

        public void rperit() {
            return perimetro;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        float base = 0, altura = 0, radio = 0;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Programa para calcular área y perímetro");
    }
}
```

Comment: If the class name is Practica_figura, then the constructor must be Practical_figura, and it does not have the "Class" in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

First, the class is not quite defined properly.

```
public class Practica_figura
{
    private float base;
    private float altura;
    private float radio;

    public Practica_figura()
    {
    }



    public void asignar(float ba, float al, float ra)
    {
      base = ba;
      altura = al;
      radio = ra;
    }

    //edits assuming you want inner classes
    class Figura
    {
      private float base, altura, radio;

      // you will need getters/setters for the variables
    }

    class Cuadrado extends Figura
    {
       // insert class logic here
    }

    class Triangulo extends Figura
    {
        // insert class logic here
    }
}
```

Second, you are shadowing variables in your child classes, and this approach may make things confusing.

Comment: It is really unclear what you are trying to accomplish.  As I, as well as @Samzerge noted, your base class definition is strange. However, assuming the goal was a Practica_figura class that has inner classes Figura, Cuadrado, and Triangulo, then you would need to do follow the edits I made above. However, you have not provided any getters/setters in the Figura class, so base, altura, and radio will be useless. The method asignar in Practica_figura cannot access the private variables in the Figura class. You are shadowing variables in your child classes.

Comment: what do you mean with "shadowing variables"?

Comment: the problem is this: 
"The classes square, circle and triangle have to calculate the area and perimeter
then it makes sense to put that functionality in a generic class as Fig.
Implement this."

oviously using inheritance

Comment: I didn't copy all of your code into the answer. However, in the code in your question, you have "float base" in the Figura class. You also have float base in your Cuadrado class. Now, it is slightly wrong since they are private, so technically they are not shadowed. However, it is going to lead to confusion. You are extending a base class, so your Cuadrado class should use the base, altura, radio variables in the base class (either through getter/setter methods in the base class or changing them to be protected instead of private) rather than re-defining them.

Answer (score 0):

To have a correct class definition change

`public class Practica_figura { Class Figura(){`

to

`public class Figura{`

I don't really understand what you were trying to do, if what you wanted was a constructor then you would have to add:

```
public Figura(){
}
```